# How to remove class with this JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is set up so it simply finds the -a's- within the class of menu-option-set, and says, upon click, add the class "selected" and remove the class "selected" from all others within that list.

What I want to do is simply have it so if you click the item that already has the class of "selected" then it removes the class of "selected".  I know it shouldn't be "return false;" I just have that as a placeholder because I can't figure out the proper coding.

Thanks guys! :)

```
var $optionSets = $('.menu-option-set'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // Remove Class if already selected --> this is the part that I need help with
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        return false;
    }

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.menu-option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.menu-option-set a').click(function()
{
    // if clicked item is selected then deselect it
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }

    // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
    else
    {
        $('.menu-option-set a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked nicely.  There have been many recommendations on this page, would this be the best way to do it though?  Or should I try it with toggle class as that's ultimately what I'm doing?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1248672. Using toggle class doesn't allow you to configure the other elements. You would maybe save one line of code but it wouldn't be as easy to read (in my opinion). There isn't a "best way" as such. Both work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use `$().removeClass('selected')` i.e.

```
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      $this.removeClass('selected');
  }
```

However, you are also adding the class again later so this should not really be necessary.

You could inline this by selecting all the `.selected` elements, removing `this` and removing the class.

```
$this
  .parents('.menu-option-set')
  .find('.selected')
  .not(this)
  .removeClass('selected');

$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I tried that initially, but it didn't work.  Just throwing that code in place of "return false;" and it didn't work, unless the order of where the "if" is changes it?

Comment: How are you determining that the class was not being removed? The class would always be added again at the end of the function.

Comment: I understand what you were saying now.  I'm sorry, flem typed it out where it should have gone, which is exactly what you said, I just had it put in the wrong place and didn't realize it.  Sorry, and thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method as follows:

```
var $optionSets = $('.menu-option-set'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.menu-option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $this.toggleClass('selected');
});​
```

**EDIT:** Added the `.not(this)` to exclude the clicked `<li>` from having the class removed before it should.

Comment: I figured that this would work and it was one of the first things that I tried, strangely, I couldn't get it working though, not sure why.  I had that exact same code.

Comment: Ah, just realised why it doesn't work. Because your `.find('.selected')` will include the clicked `<li>` if it is already selected, then you will remove the class on it, and `.toggleClass()` will re-add it.

Comment: I can't get that working, it must be something very tiny which is not allowing it to work., @flem's answer worked nicely.  I really appreciate the help though.  I really thought that a toggle would be more convenient, but I got it working without.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be concise:

```
$('.menu-option-set a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')​​;
});
```